# chectl server:deploy --platform minikube error required parameter body

Tags: parameters, null, undefined, minikube

hello first thank you for reading my question.

im using eclipse che with chectl on minikube.
when the command "chectl server:deploy --platform minikube" was inserted, i found an error "required parameter body was null or undefined when calling createNamespacedServiceAccount".

already i tried "kubectl delete namespace eclipse-che" and retried the command but it didn't work with same error.

could you answer me how to solve this problem?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

a spell ago i retried "yarn install", inserted the command and the problem was solved.

i don't know why the error comes and why solved but the thing to solve is retried "yarn install" and reinstall packages for need.